# AngularJSにて<img src=""> のsrc404エラーについて検知し代替画像を入れたい

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS1.3.0にて

```
<div ng-repeat="hoge in list">
  <img src="{{hoge.img}}">
</div>
```

のような要素があったとして、imgが外部リンクの場合は表示されないケースがあるかと思います。
この場合にデフォルトの画像をセットするような処理は可能でしょうか？

JQueryを使った場合ですと

```
    $('img').error(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            src: 'img/default.jpg'
        });
    });
```

のような記述で何とか出来そうなのはわかったのですが、AngularJS記法で
うまいことできないかなと思い質問させてもらいました。
directiveを使えばイベント取得が出来るようなことが書いてあった気がするのですが
サンプルが出来れば欲しいのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310298/if-a-ngsrc-path-resolves-to-a-404-is-there-a-way-to-fallback-to-a-default
ここの一番上の回答のディレクティブとか使えそうな気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本家stackoverflowで同じ様な質問がありコード付きで返答がありましたのでそちらを参照してはいかがでしょうか？

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17122325/1349258

**Demo**
http://plnkr.co/edit/b05WtghBOHkxKdttZ8q5?p=preview

Comment: 回答いただいた内容のng-src属性付与し、directive要素で返すことでバッチリ対応出来ました、ありがとうございます。